# How to decide which DOM element is first using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

By first I mean that opening tag of one element is earlier in HTML than the opening tag of the second.

2 elements can be totally random, can be siblings, or one can be an ascendant or descendant of the other. So the solution should be a function taking 2 random DOM elements and checking which is first in the DOM hierarchy.

Comment: Can you show us your html and what have you tried ?

Comment: @RayonDabre The question seems very clear-cut to me.

Comment: @Karol use index https://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: @FrebinFrancis works well for siblings. When I set a collection to a `body` element, and  run `index()` method on both elements, it returns me `-1` for both. As it simply has no idea. I would need to use `$('*')` as a collection, but then it will not be as efficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Node.compareDocumentPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition) to do that

```js
var node1  = document.getElementById('test1');
var node2  = document.getElementById('test2');

if ( node1.compareDocumentPosition(node2) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING ) {
    // node 1 comes before node2
} else {
    // node 2 comes before node1
}
```

```html
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
```

it returns bitmask values that tells you the first nodes position in regards to the second node

```
1  = DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED
2  = DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING
4  = DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING
8  = DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS
16 = DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY
32 = DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC
```

One could do something similar in jQuery using `index()`, but it won't be nearly as efficient

```js
$.fn.comesBefore = function(elem) {
    var all = $('*');
    return all.index(this) < all.index($(elem));
}



var node1 = $('#test1');
var node2 = $('#test2');

var result = node1.comesBefore(node2); // false, node1 comes after node2

document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div id="test2"></div>
</div>
<div id="test1"></div>
```